# How to map graphene.InputObjectType fields to kwargs?

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

Let's say we have InputObjectType:

```
class OfficeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    orderNumber = graphene.Int(required=True)
    name = graphene.String()
    streetAddress = graphene.String()
    postalCode = graphene.String()
    city = graphene.String()
```

And python class which take similar arguments, in this case we have mongoengine EmbeddedDocument:

```
class Office(EmbeddedDocument):
    orderNumber = fields.IntField(required=True)
    name = fields.StringField(default="", required=True)
    streetAddress = fields.StringField(default="", required=True)
    postalCode = fields.StringField(default="", required=True)
    city = fields.StringField(default="", required=True)
```

I would want to create Office instance by assigning OfficeInput fields to Office constructor, i.e. map OfficeInput fields to dict and pass them to constructor using python **kwargs

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find solution:

```
input_instance = OfficeInput(...)
python_class_instance = Office(**vars(input_instance))
```